# Facebook php-webdriver HAR file export

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, php-webdriver

Is there a possibility to export a HAR file from Chrome, when using facebook/php-webdriver ?

Also is it possible to select a mobile emulator on chrome and throttle the internet speed?